# Use default Common Navigator Action Set for IResource wrapper class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin.
My View extends CommonNavigator.
the View's contents is an hierarchy of MyWrapper classes

```
class MyWrapper implement IAdaptable{
IResource resource;
MyWrapper parent;
List<MyWrapper> children;
}
```

I want to display PopUp menu the same as the Default Common Navigator displays.
I have registered an AdapterFactory that adapt MyWrapper to IResource.

List of actions that are displayed:

- New
- Remove from context (disabled)
- Import
- Export
- Refresh
- Validate
- Team
- Compare with
- Restore from Local History
- Properties

List of actions that I need for menu:

- Copy
- Paste
- Rename

does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains how to add those actions: [Building a Common Navigator based viewer, Part I: Defining the Viewer](http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/2006/05/building-common-navigator-based-viewer.html)  Search for the part which adds the "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.*"